# BSonElement to c# Data Type

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an "BSonElement" in my DB and i have retry it with an standard Query.

The problem was that i can't Cast BsonDocument to Type.

Example:

**UPDATE 1:**

```
 public partial class item_Stat
{

    [BsonExtraElements]
    public BsonDocument all_stat;
}
```

Basically, i have into my DB 10-15 property (field) that I can read with "BsonExtraElements". In this way, i can retry property without define it
in C#.

all_stat, can have 10-15-20 property that dinamically change.
C# is typed language, so I can't define this property in C# and i have used ExtraElements.

The problem is when i QUERY the Object from DB.

```
var item_db = myMongoCollection.find(theQuery); // find the OBJECT

item_db.all_stat // all the property hare HERE

// find the property "category_01"
var i =  item_db.all_stat.Where(p => p.Name == "category_01").Single();

// ok, i have found the Category, so i can cast it to C# Data Type    
var typed_value = (ItemStatSingle) i.Value // BsonElement to ItemStatSingle
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of what you can do, given a class from your domain model like:

```
public class Employee
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can use your class like this:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<employee>("employees");

var employee = new Employee { Name = "John Smith" };
collection.Insert(employee);

employee = collection.FindOne();</employee>
```

Answer (score 5):

BsonElement.Value is of type BsonValue. Use one of the As* method to convert appropriately. What is the type of the value here? Since you have a user defined type your best option is to retrieve as Barrie says above. If you want to customize the "mapping" refer to the Serialization tutorial http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial

Answer (score 3):

You can't just cast a BsonDocument from your extra elements. You have to Deserialize it.

Suppose you have a class C

```
public class C
{
    public int X;
}
```

and an extraDocuments variable (analogous to your item_db.all_stat property) initialized like this:

```
var extraElements = new BsonDocument();
var c = new C { X = 1 };
extraElements["c"] = c.ToBsonDocument();
```

Then you could extract the "c" value and deserialize it like this:

```
var r = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<C>(extraElements["c"].AsBsonDocument);
Console.WriteLine(r.ToJson());
```